# Adding Number by javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript - using function</title>
<script>
function add(){
var value1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
var value2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
document.getElementById("result").value=parseFloat(value1)+parseFloat(value2);
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<label>First Number:<input type="number" id="n1"/></label>
<label>Second Number:<input type="number" id="n2"/></label>
<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="add()" />
<p>
Result = <span id="result" ></span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to JavaScript and wanted to create a script that add numbers up. After pressing "Add" button, I cannot get the result to be displayed. How to get the result displayed?

Comment: Your function looks like it should work. You just need to add an event listener so that it will be called when you click on the button.

Comment: `<input type="button" value="Add" />` change to `<input type="button" value="Add"  onclick="add()" />`

Comment: @Varun I have made the changes but the code is still not working. After pressing "Add" button, the result of the numbers is not displayed

Comment: Your question should be phrased in terms of the specific problem with your code, not the general task you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with the following changes
-> calling add function with onclick event
-> using innerhtml in place of value

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript - using function</title>
<script>
    function add(){
        var value1=document.getElementById("n1").value;
        var value2=document.getElementById("n2").value;
        console.log(value1,value2)
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=parseFloat(value1)+parseFloat(value2);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label>First Number:<input type="number" id="n1"/></label>
<label>Second Number:<input type="number" id="n2"/></label>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()"/>
<p>
Result = <span id="result" ></span>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Two things wrong here...

1)

`<input type="button" value="Add" />` change it to

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()" />
```

Also,

2)

```
document.getElementById("result").value=parseFloat(value1)+parseFloat(value2);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=parseFloat(value1)+parseFloat(value2);
```

PS : This is not a assignment solving website :P

Answer (score 1):

First, You Should Change

```
document.getElementById("result").value = value1 + value2
```

To This:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = n1 + n2
```

Because value stands for the attribute value for < input >, not the text written

in the tag.

Second, Change The Button Code To:

```
<input type="button"value="Add"onclick="add()">
```

This "onclick" is something called event in javascript,

It means at clicking on the button "Add" it performs the funtion called "add()".

If You Are New To Javascript You Will Know Everything.

Just Be Patient.

Comment: This still wont print the result!

Answer (score 0):

Its better to put the js at the end of the document - also as noted the onclick handler needs to call the function. I also tidied up the code a little.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript - using function</title>
<style>label{display:block}</style>
</head> 
<body>
  <label>First Number:<input type="number" id="n1"/></label>
  <label>Second Number:<input type="number" id="n2"/></label>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="add()">
  <p>Result = <span id="result" ></span></p>

<script>
function add(){
  var value1=parseFloat(document.getElementById("n1").value);
  var value2=parseFloat(document.getElementById("n2").value);
  var total= value1 + value2;
  document.getElementById("result").innerText=total;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```